# Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) in TFS build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-notificationhub

I have updated our **ASP.NET Web API** solution to include the **Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs** Nuget package as I want to be able to send push notifications to our mobile clients. I have written a new controller that does this. Everything works fine.

When I check-in the code changes to our on-premise TFS build server I am getting the error:

**Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

I have updated the build server to the latest VS2017 build tools but am still getting the error. I can't determine if this is an **MSBUILD** or **VS** error.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.9.4. The project uses .NET Framework 4.6.1.

**UPDATE**
After some further investigation I can see that the TFS build server is NOT restoring the Nuget package for **Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs** but restores all the other Nuget packages. So the problem seems to be due to the Nuget package not being restored during the build

Here is a screenshot showing that the *package.config* correctly references the nuget package. But for some reason this nuget package is NOT getting restored during the build.

[image]

Comment: please provide your own answer and accept it so that you can close this thread

Comment: I don't have an answer. What makes you think I do?

Comment: Oh, I see I misunderstood that from your update you got the solution. Actually your problem is NotificationHubs nuget alone not get restored? In such case can you look out the `package.config` is included with that reference ?

Comment: I've checked the packages.config and it's correctly referenced there. I've updated the build server with the latest SDKs. Same error :(

Answer (score 1):

I've eventually managed to fix this by adding a commandline nuget restore task to the build pipeline.

```
NuGet.exe restore MySolution.sln
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by uninstalling and installing the nuget package back again.